# Electron AppImage for linux doesn't start on systems with libgtk<3

Tags: electron, electron-builder

it throws an error while starting that libgtk3 cannot be find.

Is it possible to build an electron app to work on systems with libgtk2?

Actually it would be perfect if AppImage included all nesessary lib dependencies(like fuse for example), even if it would be a big filesize of image.

Comment: Gtk+ is generally regarded as a component that comes with the system (distribution) by default and is managed by it. But you can make AppImages that bundle everything (down to glibc - even though it is generally not recommended). See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/225 and https://github.com/AppImage/AppImages/issues/84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [issue #10780 on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10780), Electron upgraded back in 2017 to Chrome 61, which requires GTK+ 3. Therefore it is not possible to run Electron on a system with only GTK+ 2 installed.

[The idea of AppImages](https://appimage.org/) is that an application should contain all libraries it needs to run. However, libraries like GTK+ need to integrate deeply into the system (GTK+ requires `libXrandr.so`, `libglib.so`, etc. just to name a few) and have a ton of dependencies which would blow the package up. It is therefore pretty difficult to build an app which contains all different dependencies it has (and even imagine having three or more AppImages containing GTK+ and dependencies sitting on your hard drive).

And in the case of GTK+, it is in most use-cases not enough to just install `libgtk` (any version), because you might want to profit from dependencies which are just "recommended".

Comment: What if that old libs would lay in electron catalogue and it uses they instead of system libs?

Comment: What do you mean with "electron catalogue"?

Comment: Electron creates an image and include inside a couple of .so files(libffmpeg.so, libnode.so) why didn't he store another nesessary files there?

Comment: I believe it includes the NodeJS and FFMpeg libraries because these need to be the exact version to which the app was compiled against, but including GTK+, for example, would blow up the image way too much (and because GTK+ depends on some other libraries, which go way deeper into the system). Btw, the [LibreOffice AppImage](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/) also does not contain GTK+, most likely due to the integration issue.

Comment: Thank you. Why does vscode not list gtk3 as a requirement? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

Comment: All Linux OSses listed under "VS Code was tested..." ship with GTK+ (because all of them ship with GNOME/GNOME-like environments by default).